# O que tem de errado nesse código Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Queria adicionar a class `tab-active` a todos as tag `span` da div `menuMobileTabs`. O que há de errado?

```
<div id='menuMobileTabs'>
  <span>Sidebar</span>
  <span>RedeSociais</span>
  <span>Menu</span>
  <span>Search</span>
</div>

<script>
var menuTabs = document.querySelector('#menuMobileTabs span'); 

for(var i = 0;i < menuTabs.length;i++){
  menuTabs[i].classList.add('tab-active');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Pronto. Ta ai! O CDATA é por causa que uso blogger.

Comment: Melhorou bastante com o código, facilita muito pra quem vai testar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize querySelectorAll para buscar a lista de elementos, o querySelector vai trazer apenas o primeiro span neste caso.

Answer (score 4):

Se menuTabs é um array, você pode acessar ele sem um índice, com está fazendo nessa linha:

```
menuTabs.classList.add('tab-active');
```

O correto seria:

```
menuTabs[i].classList.add('tab-active');
```

Além disso, `querySelector` pode trazer um elemento, use `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 3):

Tem que utilizar o [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) em vez de [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) a diferença é que ele pega todas as ocorrências e não apenas uma (no caso o primeiro `span`).

```js
var menuTabs = document.querySelectorAll('#menuMobileTabs span');

for(i = 0; i < menuTabs.length; i++)
{
  menuTabs[i].classList.add("tag-active");
}
```

```css
.tag-active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuMobileTabs">
  <span>Siber</span>
  <span>Rede Sociais</span>
  <span>Menu</span>
  <span>Search</span>
</div>
```

---

Pode trabalhar de maneira resumida:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#menuMobileTabs span').forEach(function(el)
{
   el.classList.add("tag-active");
});
```

```css
.tag-active {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuMobileTabs">
  <span>Siber</span>
  <span>Rede Sociais</span>
  <span>Menu</span>
  <span>Search</span>
</div>
```

**Referencias**

- [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Loop Over querySelectorAll Matches](https://coderwall.com/p/jcmzxw/iterate-over-queryselectorall-result)

Answer (score 1):

O erro está no `querySelector`, você tem que usar o `querySelectorAll`, assim pega todas as ocorrências.